# Cassandra 1.1: querying multiple row keys, but not a range

Tags: cassandra, rows, cql

I have read a lot of documentation about building reverse indexes in Cassandra, but I've seen nothing about how to then use these results to fetch the applicable rows.

I know about row slices, but that doesn't apply here. My question is: how does one fetch a large number of specific rows according to the row key?

In pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table where Primark_Key IN (2, 32, 76, 1000, 2427)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [multiget_slice](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API#multiget_slice) is what you're looking for. Takes in a list of keys to go fetch. It's worth bearing in mind that it's not particularly efficient; although often the only choice.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate on why this isn't efficient?

Comment: Sure - basically because each key may be stored somewhere different on your ring there's not much cassandra can do to optimise and will essentially get one at a time. This may be totally fine, its just worth thinking about especially if your multiget's end up asking for a large number of keys.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you perform a multiget, the coordinator will request individual rows from different nodes in parallel.  When a single node has to read multiple rows, it's basically sequential.  Overall, multigets do not tend to be efficient; a wide row model (typically requiring denormalization) should be used when possible.

Comment: If you have a lot of keys and calling multiget_slice will probably end up in TimedOutException.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but can someone tell me if multiget_slice results keeps input order? I'm assuming No.

Answer (score 3):

The pseudo-SQL you posted is a valid CQL query, too